# C# WPF GUI performance MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I'm looking for a way to improve performances of my code. I've got a WPF GUI with a TextBox and a graph (from OxyPlot package). I used StopWatch to find the place where the code is less efficient and I found that it takes more time to update the Text of my TextBox than to fill the string. For example, if the property `MyText` is bound to the Text property of the TextBox then this part of code

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{
   MyText = currentString;
});
```

takes more time than all of this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
RetrieveDataFromDevice();
FillString(sb);
string currentString = sb.ToString();
```

And with the StopWatch :

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
   var sw = new StopWatch();
   sw.Start();
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   RetrieveDataFromDevice();
   FillString(sb);
   string currentString = sb.ToString();
   Trace.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()); //5ms
   sw.Restart();
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{
      MyText = currentString;
   });
   Trace.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()); //10ms
}
```

There is a performance issue as I can not refresh the string (or the graph) more often than every 15ms. Are there any way to improve these performances ?

Comment: Why do you want to update the user interface more frequently than 15 ms? The human eye can not perceive such a frequency.

Comment: The point is that I had to disable the GUI update when I wanted to run faster for later analysis (as my data is also saved into file). I used to lower frequencies, but as I would like to see faster phenomenon on my data, I tried to decrease the delay between two measurements and I noticed that the GUI was the bottleneck. The solution was to disable GUI refresh but I wanted to explore other solutions. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead of the Invoke method.

This method does not wait for the UI thread to process the request before being able to continue. It simply puts the request in the UI thread's queue and then returns immediately.

This will allow you to do more processing in the background thread while the UI thread is processing UI requests.

Having said that, there should be a reasonable amount of UI update requests that you ask the UI thread to process per second.

Comment: I was wondering why all my process were synchronous... shame on me. Thanks !